# visual basic 6 code with mysql server not responding

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

i have a code that i connect to mysql and get the data and compare it 
and the code work 
but after 2 min it not responding

if i removed the line

```
Call connectMysql("root", "pass", "localhost", "ha", conn, rs)
```

from the loop and put it out side the loop it doesn't not responding but the code doesn't work and doesn't get the data from mysql

so any one has idea ??

here is the code wish is work but after 2 min not responding

```
ssql = "SELECT data FROM main"

 ' Do
  Dim intX As Integer

intX = 0
Do Until intX = 10

      Call connectMysql("root", "pass", "localhost", "ha", conn, rs)


rs.Open ssql, conn

      Temp = rs.Fields(0)

         If lasttemp <> Temp Then
         lasttemp = Temp

      End If
    intX = intX + 1
     Ret = DoEvents()
    If intX = 8 Then intX = 0
    Loop
```

and here is the code which doesn't not responding and also doesn't gret the data

```
ssql = "SELECT data FROM main"

 ' Do
  Dim intX As Integer

intX = 0
Do Until intX = 10

      Call connectMysql("root", "pass", "localhost", "ha", conn, rs)


rs.Open ssql, conn

      Temp = rs.Fields(0)

         If lasttemp <> Temp Then
         lasttemp = Temp

      End If
    intX = intX + 1
     Ret = DoEvents()
    If intX = 8 Then intX = 0
    Loop
```

Comment: Probably because you have an infinite loop. `until intX = 10`, but the when intx starts gettting close to 10 (8, really), you reset it to 0.

Comment: i did the same code with out Call connectMysql("root", "pass", "localhost", "ha", conn, rs) and kept the loop and it works but with no connection with mysql